# Awk function arguments

Tags: awk

I am having trouble understanding the use of gawk function arguments.
Customarily, arguments define variables that are local to the function.

But can arguments be used as input that the function can use ?

Have seen the use of `return` which can actually return a value by calling

```
val=myfunc()
```

What is the advantage of passing a global value as an input argument to a function, when you can access the global variable nonetheless ?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and clarify? Perhaps give an example function and explain what you would expect? Also, gawk is a specific implementation of awk, although I doubt it would behave differently in this case, so it is a bit confusing that you use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: Please get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as it explains this (which you've already asked variations of) and everything else you've been asking about from your many accounts here and on SO (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75941917/1745001 and many others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is based on a false premise.

> Customarily, arguments define variables that are local to the function.

No. Customarily, arguments define variable names for values passed in to the function.

`awk` doesn't have the ability to declare locally scoped variables. But since all function arguments are optional, it's considered acceptable practice to overload the function argument list with variables that have no purpose other than that they can be used locally in the function.

Therefore the answer to your question is "yes": variables can be used to pass in values to a function.

For example,

```
awk '
    function factorial(n) { return n>1 ? n*factorial(n-1) : 1 }
    BEGIN { print factorial(5) }
'
```

Here the function calls itself with a different value each time (first 5 and then descending values 4, 3, 2). Trying to use a global variable for this would be exceedingly hard.

Comment: I have experience in `C` and `Fortran` where arguments can be used for input and output.  In awk though. function arguments cannot be used for outputting values through argument names.  That is why I described them as local.

Comment: If awk doesn't have the ability to declare locally scoped variables, why is it that when one does not add the names as arguments, the global values get changed ?

Comment: @Heime, function arguments can't be used for output in C. You might be thinking of pointers, which can of course be used to modify variables somewhere else, but the pointer itself as an argument is still input only. (The pointer itself is passed by value, if you like that nomenclature.)

Comment: @Heime, anyway, I'm not exactly sure what it is you're asking there? Are you asking if there's a point in passing arguments to functions instead of just using global variables always, everywhere? What if the programmer wants the function to use variable A at one point, and variable B at another...? It might help if you could [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/742079/edit) your question to demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: @Heime  As noted in my previous answer: (a) Awk can declare locally scoped variables as excess arguments. If you do not declare their names like that, they are assumed to be global. (b) Array arguments can be written into by their function -- they **are** passed by reference. This is all in GNU Awk Users Guide 9.2.3.2.

Comment: Regarding "I have experience in C and Fortran where arguments can be used for input and output." - I've seen you use that terminology about argument "input" and "output" in other questions and it's causing a lot of confusion as "input" is what's read by the script and "outputting" an argument from a function means printing it's value. I THINK what you're trying to say is something like "I have experience in C and Fortran where arguments can be passed in to a function and populated by it".

Comment: @EdMorton with Fortran you can pass arguments into a function/procedure by value and by reference. (In C likewise, but typically more obviously as `&var`.) If you pass by reference then changing them inside the function will affect the value outside. Thus you can say such an argument is passed for output.

Comment: @roaima yes, I understand, but in this context IMO it's unclear and ambiguous at best to talk about outputting arguments instead of populating arguments.

Comment: I agree.  By output I mean this - changing the value of an argument for use outside the function.  For instance, it does not seem  possible to reset more than a single variable for use outside the function.  Suppose I want a function that takes two numbers, and want to output two variable values, one containing the sum, the other containing the average.  What can one do?

Comment: Global variables or an array, @Heime. `awk 'function sa(a, b, x) { x[1] = a+b; x[2] = x[1]/2 } BEGIN { sa(2, 3, r); print r[1], r[2] }'`

Comment: Which effectively means that apart from using `result var`, any output has to involve global variables. because arrays do have global scope.

Comment: @Heime, an array name as a function argument (`x` in my example) is local to the function. If you have a global `x` array it remains untouched by operations performed on the local array named `x` - operations on this local `x` only affect the array `r` passed in to the function

Comment: Arrays do ***not*** necessarily have global scope. If you define an array as an additional function argument, its scope becomes private to that function. Please stop trying to intuit a language definition from a few trivial online examples of simple code, badly implemented. You are directly contradicting the authoritative GNU manual which I referenced above: that section has the heading **"Controlling Variable Scope"**.

Comment: @Heime further to Paul_Pedant's note, if you declare an array as a function argument but _do not_ pass in a named array, you have effectively created a locally scoped anonymous array that you can use in whatever way you want. In my example this would be equivalent to calling `sa(2, 3)`. Inside the function you have the array `x` that's locally scoped with no global equivalent

Comment: @Heime  I edited my previous answer to include a code that shows precisely "what can one do", and proves the global/local point too. Of course, another solution is to return a single string from the calculation function like `6.2|3.1|9.45`, and `split()` it in the calling function. But this becomes cumbersome for many results, and requires a separator that cannot occur in the data. Also, an associative array can be used to label the elements, with results like `X["Sum"] = 6.2`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I ask questions or imply conclusions for criticism and correction.  I am happy about your elaborations about global and local scope.

Answer (score 3):

Note also that scalar arguments to a function are passed by value, but array arguments are passed by reference. Thus, the function can change array values declared in the calling code to that function, and so return multiple values.

That includes the ability to create new elements in an array argument, even if it was initially passed in as an empty array.

> Suppose I want a function that takes two numbers, and want to output
> two variable values, one containing the sum, the other containing the
> average. What can one do?

One can do this: it demonstrates that global and local scopes exist for arrays of the same name, that they can be of different lengths and contain different data, and that an array is passed by reference and can return multiple values.

```
#! /bin/bash

Awk='
#.. Define and fill an array X at global scope.
BEGIN { X[1] = 45; X[2] = 98; }
#.. Function that fills in a result array (passed by reference).
function Math (X, v1, v2) {
    X[1] = v1 + v2; X[2] = (v1 + v2) / 2; X[3] = v1 * v2;
}
#.. Function that declares an array X at local scope, and reports it.
function Wrapper (a, b,      X, j) {
    Math( X, a, b);
    for (j = 1; j in X; ++j) printf ("Local X[%d] is %f\n", j, X[j]);
}
{ 
    Wrapper( $1, $2);
    #.. Prove that the Global X is unaffected, in length or content.
    for (j = 1; j in X; ++j) printf ("Global X[%d] is %f\n", j, X[j]);
}
'   
    echo 3.5 2.7 | awk "${Awk}"
```

```
$ ./Heime.awk
Local X[1] is 6.200000
Local X[2] is 3.100000
Local X[3] is 9.450000
Global X[1] is 45.000000
Global X[2] is 98.000000
```

GNU Awk runs this just fine -- it decides the type of X when it is first accessed. `nawk` (Solaris Awk) seems to make that decision when it is passed in (and may SegViol as a result).

To ensure `nawk` passes X into the function by reference, you may need to explicitly create it as a zero-length array before passing it in, by splitting a zero-length string using a zero-length pattern:

```
    split ("", X, ""); Math( X, a, b);
```

Comment: Why would one declare array arguments if they are global.  There would be no need.  It started some confusion for me.

Comment: @Heime If you wite a function to print the elements of an array in a certain way, where the array is passed to the function, that function could be used to print any array. If you used a global array in the  function, only that array would be able to be printed.

Comment: @Heime  The distinction is not as distinct as global or local. Because awk functions can call other functions to any (reasonable)  depth, I can create and populate a local array in an intermediate level function, and pass that array to one or more utility functions as an argument. It is generally considered good practice to avoid creating global variables as much as possible.

Comment: Regarding "Why would one declare array arguments if they are global. There would be no need." - to write your code using the fundamentals of all software development: encapsulation, tight cohesion, and loose coupling.

Comment: If I avoid  using any global variables in a function called `this_func`, is `return var` and `arrays` the only ways to pass updated arguments in `this_func` to be used for `that_func` ?  E.g. `that_func() { r=0 ; s=0 ; this_func(r,s) ; print r s }`

Comment: @Heime  Until you specify the outermost level at which `r` and `s` are declared, and the calling relationship between `this_func` and `that_func`, the question in that comment has no possible meaning. How is the e.g an example of a comment that mentions `return` and `arrays` when it contains neither? Please at least make an attempt to post real code that takes real input, produces real output, and illustrates an issue that actually exists elsewhere than in your febrile imagination.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the advantage of passing a global value as an input argument to a function, when you can access the global variable nonetheless ?

Same as with any function in any programming language: you can pass a different (global) variable each time, and the function doesn't need to know about things it doesn't need for doing it's job.

As a trivial example:

```
function sum(a,b) { return a+b; }

{ partial = sum($2, $3); }
$1 == 0 { print sum(partial, $4); }
$1 != 0 { print sum(partial, $5); }
```

Imagine a more involved function there in place of `sum()`, so that duplicating it in both branches would no longer make sense.

Comment: Fantastic explanation that helps explain the necessity of function arguments in awk..  In the example one can pass any variable, whether global or not.  The function then becomes a sort of generic function seen in programming languages.  Although experienced with programming languages, I was hesitant about the peculiarities of awk function programming.

Comment: @Heime, umh, _"The function then becomes a sort of generic function seen in programming languages"_... well, I wonder, what did you expect, then? And isn't AWK a programming language itself?

Comment: I find the awk syntax for local variable definition quite appalling.

Comment: @Heime  The (empty) syntax grows on you -- there are other examples to be appalled by. The conventional way to differentiate local variables is to leave a gap between the args and the locals. However, I prefer to show them like `myFunc (a, b, Local, c, d, e) { ...`. Note that `Local` is not an awk keyword, it is merely the name of the first (unused) local variable (and itself has local scope, so it can safely be used in every function).

Comment: I know that I can pass values `a` and `b` to `myFunc`.  But I certainly cannot change them.  Thus `r=3 ; s=5 ; myFunc(r,s) ; print r s`  will keep `r` and `s` with values `3` and `5` respectively, even though the values are changed inside `myFunc`.  Although they look like arguments, their values cannot be changed by the function so that their updated values can be used elsewhere.  I would like to have a function that compute some complicated values from some input data, so I can use the computed values in the body of my awk script.  Something that is creating me a lot of problems.

Comment: Take the serious task of a function that gives me some complicated dynamic pattern matching string.  How can I be able to access it in the body of my awk script?  Quite difficult.

Comment: @Heime, sigh. If you wanted to ask about returning multiple values from a function, why didn't you say that in the first place? Now your question says "But can arguments be used as input that the function can use ?", i.e. mentioning input, not output. You've sent people off on a futile job to explain the basic stuff on that and now it appears it wasn't your question anyway.

Comment: @Heime, also, you said "Although they look like arguments, their values cannot be changed by the function so that their updated values can be used elsewhere." and I wonder why that's so surprising: it's the way function arguments work in many if not most common programming languages, at least e.g. C, Python and Perl... (possibly in part because that's what the straightforward implementation of passing arguments on a stack results in)