# Setting values through awk function calls

Tags: awk

I am using GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 and have the following awk script.  Testing this has shown that one can never use a function argument to change the variable used as input to it.  Thus in the following example, one gets `p: 21`.  Meaning that as long as pass a variable as an argument to the function, I would not be able to change it to something else after the function terminates.  Is this correct?

```
awk '
    function solarex_nuclmn(e) {
        e = 34
    }

    BEGIN {
        p = 21
        solarex_nuclmn(p)
        print "p: " p
    }
'
```

I understand that I can get the value `p: 34` using `return e`.

```
awk '
    function solarex_nuclmn(e) {
        e = 34
        return e
    }

    BEGIN {
        p = 21
        p = solarex_nuclmn()
        print "p: " p
    }
'
```

Then there is the possibility to using global variable.  Although most times people would like to avoid using global variable.

```
awk '
    function solarex_nuclmn(e) {
        G = 34
    }

    BEGIN {
        G = 21
        solarex_nuclmn()
        print "G: " G
    }
'
```

Finally the possibility of using an array

```
awk '
    function solarex_nuclmn(a) {
        a[0] = 34
    }

    BEGIN {
        a[0] = 21
        solarex_nuclmn(a)
        print "a[0]: " a[0]
    }
'
```

And that is all.  There are no other possibilities for having `p: 34`, am I right?  Either use `return`, `global`, or `array`.  For changing multiple values, the best way would be to pass an array as argument (because one can change array element values and also add additional array elements).

I am looking for a portable way for a function to change values outside the scope of the function.  But if there is something specific to GAWK, I would also like to hear it.

Comment: Function call arguments are local. You can't change globals this way. Use return values or just modify the global in the function body.

Comment: I know how to use return value but not how to use globals.

Comment: It looks like you just want to define an array, but you can also make a function that returns a value based on the value fed in.

Comment: I am totally confused.  I want the return the value of `e`,  But not with `return e`.  Can I pass a variable as argument and get it changed by the function.  Example `p=0 ; solarex_nuclmn(p) ; print p` and get `p` print `34`.

Comment: If you **don't** want `p` to be local, then **don't** pass it as a formal parameter - see for example [Controlling Variable Scope](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Scope)

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use `p = solarex_nuclmn()`? Or put the magic number in a global and copy it from there as needed? Your code snippet there shows multiple values, if they're related to each other, would it make sense to put them in an array instead of individual vars? (Esp. since then you could have a function to fill the values in to a referenced array)

Comment: The code in your question was far more complicated than necessary to demonstrate your needs so I tidied it up. Going forward please post minimal, complete verifiable examples that **only** demonstrate the problem you're asking about, not just whatever code you have lying around that includes the problem somewhere, so it's as easy as possible for as many people as possible to help you.

Comment: Regarding `Somehow, the value is getting assumed to be of local scope` - see the answers+comments to your questions from 2 days ago (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/742079/133219 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941917/using-awk-functions-in-different-sections) and others for the explanation of `Somehow`.

Comment: [edit] your question to state which awk version you're using (e.g. output of `awk --version`) and tell us if you want a portable solution that'll work across all awks or are happy with a non-portable solution that'll only work in GNU awk as there's a different answer for GNU awk than for other awk variants.

Comment: Regarding your newly added "But if there is something specific to GAWK, I would also like to hear it." - you already heard it, see `SYMTAB` in [@meuh's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742298/133219).

Comment: If you are able to change the value of `p` when you pass it to a function as `myFunc(p);`, exactly what would you expect to happen when you pass a value in with `myFunc(2);`? Should *all* variables with the value `2` in your entire script be changed to `34`? How about `myFunc(sqrt(77))`? Your requirement is ludicrous because function arguments are not necessarily variables. Arrays can be passed by reference because they are by definition an (array of) variables. This is not a language issue, it is a basic requirement of how functions work in any language (even machine code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but here are 3 uses of functions in
GNU awk showing typical uses of the arguments and return values:

```c
function f(a,b){ return a+b; }
function g(a,b){ A=a; B=b; }
function h(a,b){ SYMTAB[a] = SYMTAB[b]; }
BEGIN{
  A=99; B=88; a=77; b=66;
  x=f(1,2);   print "x=" x
  g(4,5);     print "A=" A, "B=" B
  h("A","B"); print "A=" A
}
```

`f()` returns a value so it is used in expressions and assignments such as
`x=f(1,2)`. `g()` sets globals `A` and `B`. They are globals because they
are not in the parameter list `a,b`.  `h()` implements a sort of *call by
name*, where a global name is passed in as a string, and the global
variable of that name is accessed via the GNU builtin `SYMTAB` symbol table.
This produces the output

```
x=3
A=4 B=5
A=5
```

Comment: Correct, I understand your examples.  What I want to confirm is that if a pass a variable (`p = 21` say) as argument, I can never get the function to change the value of the argument to something else (e.g. `p = 34`), which I can use after calling `solarex_nuclmn(p)`.  Meaning that `solarex_nuclmn(p) ; print p` will never give me a value of `p` equal to the value changed by the function.

Comment: Every variable in awk is global, except within a function when all the formal parameters in the definition are local. If `p` is not in the formal parameters of function `f` then calling `f` can change `p`. Eg `function f(a,b){p=34;}` called with `f()` or `f(99)` or `f(p)` *will* change `p`. If you have a function `g(a,b,p){p=33;}` then calling `g` 
 will not change global `p`. But if `g(a,b,p){f();}` then `g()` will change global `p`.

Comment: I am only considering the case when the variable names `a` and `b` are in the formal parameter arguments of function `f(a, b)`.  Then the function `f(a, b)` can never change `a` and `b` outside the function scope.

Comment: @Heime no, because `f(a, b)` is explicitly creating two new, local variables named `a` and `b` which only exist inside the function. If you also have another `a` variable somewhere, that is not affected.

Comment: I did more tests and that's how it is @terdon.  On a more serious note I have a function that constructs three patterns `p1`, `p2`, `p3` using input data as arguments `a`, `b`, `c`.  The way to output the three patterns is via an array `ptrns`, thus `func_patterns (a, b, c, ptrns)`.  Then I can use `ptrns` in the main awk body.  Either that or using global variables.

Comment: Again, you're not trying to **output** the arguments, you are trying to **populate** them. See the comments and answers associated with your previous questions for the confusion you're causing by using the term "output" in this context.

Comment: Right.  Because using print within a function is considered output.  You are correct. my meaning is populating the values of arguments.